# Projection of a plane onto a surface of sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, projective-geometry

What is the effect on the plane equation of projecting a plane onto the surface of a sphere.

Assume we are starting with the standard point-normal plane equation:

$$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$

or alternatively:

$$\hat{n}x + d = 0$$

where $\hat{n}$ is the plane normal, $x$ is a point on the plane, and $d$ is the distance from the origin.

Mathematically, how does one project this plane onto a sphere?

Comment: How do you define projection of a plane on a spherical surface? By the way, what is a spherical surface? Just a sphere?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Yeah I had trouble articulating this. Onto a the surface of a sphere is a better way to say it. And projection of a plane is basically warping the plane onto the surface of a sphere.

Comment: @marcman "wrapping the plane onto the surface of a sphere" doesn't make sense either though: there is no isometric map from a region of the plane to a region of the sphere. Intuitively you've likely discovered this yourself, when trying to gift-wrap a round object, and noticing that no matter what you do the wrapping paper "puckers"

Comment: @user7530: That's not entirely true. Sure, for physical objects perhaps. But in the case I'm referring to it's entirely plausible that the plane should deform. Think of panoramas and [image stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching) where planes on images are projected onto a sphere.